# Calcular diferença entre datas e alterar status

Tags: c#, mysql

Preciso criar alguma rotina para calcular a diferença entre duas datas diretamente no banco de dados MySql e mudar o status de outro campo de acordo com essa diferença.
Os campos do banco de dados são :

1. Data Calibração,
2. Vencimento Calibração,
3. Status Calibração : Em dia,
                       Calibrar,
                       Vencida.

Como faço para criar a rotina que pegue as duas datas faça o  calculo da diferença e quando a data for superior a 30 dias o status seja "em dia", quando for inferior a 30 dias o status seja "Calibrar" e quando a data for maior que o campo "vencimento calibração" o status seja "Vencida" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou lhe responder como fazer isso no Banco de Dados, vou lhe propor uma forma que (em minha opinião) seja mais adequada para valores calculados. Onde estes campos calculados não seriam campos salvos no banco de dados mas sim calculados baseados em seus indicadores.

Vantagem:

- O campo será recalculado a cada nova requisição ao mesmo, baseado no estado atual do objeto;
- Você não necessita de Procedures, Functions, ou Triggers para essa tarefa vinculados aos banco de dados;
- Você não corre o risco do campo calculado ficar desatualizado baseado em seus indicadores;
- Entre outras inúmeras vantagens menores que é possível apontar facilmente;

Desvantagens:

- Se o banco for utilizado por mais de um sistema, todos os envolvidos terão que incorporar a regra para calcular os campos calculados;
- Se você não utiliza modelo de Classes (Atribui o cursor da query diretamente ao DataSource (particularmente não recomendo));

**Implementação**

Seria algo similar a isso em C# (que parece ser a linguagem que você está utilizando):

```
public class Calibragem{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime Vencimento { get; set; }
    public StatusCalibragem Status { 
        get{
            // aqui você faz a conta da diferença em mémoria
            /** 
             * DUVIDA: aqui você não deveria calcula a Data da ultima calibragem com a 
             * data atual(DateTime.Now) ou o Vencimento com a data atual(DateTime.Now),
             * ao invés de fazer o calculo entre as duas Datas?
            **/    
            TimeSpan diff = Data - Vencimento;

            // verifica a diferença em dias para ver qual o status atual
            if(diff.Days > 30){
                return StatusCalibragem.EmDia;
            }
            if(diff.Days < 30){
                return StatusCalibragem.Calibrar;
            }
            // não entendi quando será Vencida, com sua explicação
        } 
        private set; 
    }
}

public enum StatusCalibragem
{
    EmDia,
    Calibrar,
    Vencida
}
```

No banco de dados sua tabela só teria as colunas:

```
ID | DATA_CALIBRAGEM | VENCIMENTO_CALIBRAGEM
```

Comment: Entendi Fernando. Vou tentar aplicar seu exemplo no sistema. Dessa forma acho que consigo exibir esses status no meu listview. Porque alem de atualizar esse status preciso exibir. Nunca utilizei classes, mas vou tentar aplicar no código que já tenho.

Comment: @PhilipeSaid, acho que será adequado ao seu cenário. E recomendo criar camadas em seus sistema e classes de modelos, pois utilizar o Cursor das consultas diretamente na View pode parecer pratico no inicio, mas a medida que a aplicação cresce e as manutenções consequentemente também, não ter camadas e classes tornam as coisas muito mais difíceis de serem controladas. Mas isso é questão mais de opinião!

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer a atualização da coluna de acordo com as condições de data você pode usar algo assim:

```
UPDATE suatabela
   SET status = CASE WHEN CURDATE > data_vencimento THEN
                   status1
                ELSE
                   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), data_calibragem) > 30 THEN
                      status2
                   ELSE
                      status3
                   END   
                END;
```

Lembrando que com essa instrução todos os registros da tabela serão afetados. Pois em algum momento, cada um estará em uma das 3 situações citadas por você.

Observações:

- `CURDATE` retorna o dia atual
  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).
- `DATEDIFF` retorna a diferença entre duas datas (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Para que essa instrução seja executada diariamente você deve criar um *event* no banco de dados (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html).

Um exemplo:

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT e_upd_calibragem
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Atualiza status de calibragem'
    DO
      BEGIN

        UPDATE suatabela
           SET status = CASE WHEN CURDATE > data_vencimento THEN
                           status1
                        ELSE
                           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), data_calibragem) > 30 THEN
                              status2
                           ELSE
                              status3
                           END   
                        END;

      END |

delimiter ;
```

Comment: esse código que enviou seria uma trigger correto ? Como cada linha do banco tem uma data especifica, essa rotina seria executada calculando sempre todas as linhas certo de acordo com a execução desse evento. A trigger seria mais indicada do que utilizar código direto na aplicação para fazer esse calculo ?

Comment: Não, isso não é uma TRIGGER, é um JOB ou no caso do MySQL, um EVENT. Este código é agendado para execução de acordo com o período desejado. No exemplo seria executado uma vez por dia: `ON SCHEDULE  EVERY 1 DAY`. Dessa forma, a cada dia a tabela teria todos os seus status atualizados, já que a variação no valor de status depende da data. A vantagem dessa abordagem é que a execução é agendada, não necessita de intervenção do usuário, e fica independente de aplicação. Posso fazer uma app web, mobile ou desktop apenas consultando os dados no banco. As regras de negócio ficam no banco.

Comment: tentei aplicar seu código aqui mas deu erro no END CASE.

Comment: Me desculpa, erro meu. Termina só em END, não END CASE. Corrigi o exemplo. Além disso tem um código do UPDATE funcionando aqui pra você ver http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d1c13 . Acessa e faz um SELECT pra testar.

Comment: Tentei executar o script que mandou mas não consegui. Estou navalhando em alguma coisa. O script que postou mais cedo já carreguei ele no mysql, so que quando vou executar estar sinalizando erro nessa linha ( UPDATE tb_instrumento  SET Status = CASE WHEN CURDATE > Data_Calibracao ). Já carregou o evento no banco mas não executou.

Comment: Consegui executar, mas vou ter que modificar meu sistema, tenho um DateTimePicker e um textbox, que são os que gravo as datas. O valor da data que preciso utilizar para executar o evento pega o formato diferente de data onde da confronto com o formato a ser analisado pelo evento. Mas de qualquer forma o código que me passou funciona. Vou tentar modificar esse DateTimePicker por um MaskedBox. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que o código foi útil. Quanto ao formato da data, talvez você possa usar alguma função que converta a data pra você, ou na própria aplicação ou no banco. É uma alternativa pra não ter que trocar os DateTimePicker.

Comment: Inseri um evento no banco que fará essa conversão

_'UPDATE tbl_data SET data =
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE data LIKE '__/__/____' '_ . Funcionou perfeitamente.